# Angular $resource to get several records

Tags: angularjs, angular-fullstack

I have the following ids:

```
var myIds = ['somelongId', 'someotherlongid'];
```

I want to get only the records that correspond from mongo (I am using angular-fullstack) using $resource.

**My factory**

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .factory('MyFactory',function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/things/:id');
});
```

**My faulty code returns all the records**

```
MyFactory.query(myIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should query correctly, by passing id parameter in it. You can't pass array object inside query, if you try to pass that then that will make stringify that array to `[Object Object]` & it will throw an error.

Instead I'd suggest you to pass any one of id to it.

```
MyFactory.query({ id: myIds[0] });
```

**Edit**

If you wanted to pass multiple `ids` in a query statement then pass it as `,` separated string and then do split out that key on server side. In that way you could pass multiple array to server & will get array of response(`.query` will make thing done).

```
MyFactory.query({ id: myIds.join(',') });
```

This will create url as

```
http://localhost/api/things/somelongId,someotherlongid
```

Comment: Do you mean `MyFactory.get`? `MyFactory.query` expects a response with array and I will only get one record with what you are suggesting (Error: `Expected response to contain an array but got an object`). Also do you mean that the correct design pattern is to make a separate request for each item in my array?

Comment: If its gonna return single record then use MyFactory.get

Comment: id's are unique so yes it will. But is there a way to return a list of records when I give it a list of ids?

Comment: You need to pass `, ` seperated list to server instead of passing it as an array..that will do the trick

Comment: Thanks but it's a really dirty approach. Also, I can split my array on the server side as well but it's messy. There must be a way to get mongoose to query for a list of items but maybe not.

Comment: @Mika why you think that its dirty approach? Passing an array in get request isn't possible AFAIK.. this is normal thing to pass multiple ids in get request..

Comment: Because using get for several records is not what get is for. It breaks all the CRUD rules...

Comment: @Mika that's why `query` method is there.. which will think that data comes back server will be in array format, that will act same as `get` request

Comment: I understand that... But how do I give the query function a list of IDs that is what I am trying to get to...

Comment: @Mika may I know what should be the URL while passing multiple ids to server?

Comment: It's the standard yomean angular-fullstack endpoint. With no changes.

Comment: @Mika see honestly speaking I'm not aware of angular-fullstack endpoint.. could you provide me how your URL going to form?